# Facebook like button disappears

Tags: html, facebook

I have a problem with Facebook Like button in my site:
adding this code (provided by facebook)

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://my.site.com/folder/&send=false&layout=button_count&width=120&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=20" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:20px;">
```

button is correctly shown in any page as it is created, after a few days on some pages iframe remains empty because Facebook don't send the button code anymore.

I tried to solve eventual url problems and changing some urls I noticed that the button shows in new urls, after few days some page looses button.

This is all the code coming from Facebook after page without Like button is loaded:

```
<html lang="it" id="facebook" class="no_js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir"/>
<meta name="referrer" content="default" id="meta_referrer"/>
<meta name="description" content=" Facebook è una piattaforma sociale che ti consente di connetterti con i tuoi amici e con chiunque lavori, studi e viva vicino a te. Puoi usare Facebook per rimanere in contatto con i tuoi amici, caricare tutte le foto che vuoi, pubblicare link e video o per saperne di più sulle persone che incontri."/>
<script/>
<title>Facebook</title>
<script>var onloadRegister_DEPRECATED=function(){},onafterloadRegister_DEPRECATED=function(){},ServerJSQueue={add:function(){}};
</script>
<style type="text/css"> div.fbNubFlyoutBody.scrollable{position:inherit}
</style>
<script>ServerJSQueue.add({"require":[["lowerDomain"],["Primer"]]});</script>
</head>
<body class="opera Locale_it_IT">
<div id="FB_HiddenContainer" style="position:absolute; top:-10000px; width:0px; height:0px;"/>
<script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{Env=window.Env||{};b(Env);}}
envFlush        ({"fb_dtsg":"XXXXXXXXXX","ajaxpipe_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","lhsh":"XXXXXXXXX","user":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"});</script>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The moste evident difference is in:

```
<html lang="it" id="facebook" class="no_js">
```

that in working pages has class="".
In working pages there's also a lot of more code...

Can anybody help or give a hint to let me understand what's going on?

---

Thanks for the answer, but that's not the solution, this is the code as provided by facebook and as I said works at the time url is created and, only for some pages, stops working after few days.
Anyway I found in facebook developer site that's a known bug with medium priority.

Answer (score 2):

It appears this might be this bug:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335818753176892/

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/130242697118406/

Essentially, if the Facebook App you are creating the Like button with is:

- In 'sandbox' mode, or
- Has a different domain to the one the Like button is being generated  on

Then this problem can appear. Both of these can be changed by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and selecting the app in question.

In my case, I had originally set the App URL to `localhost` for development. I have added the correct URL, along with the subdomains we use, but as yet it has not started working again. I'll update this answer with more information as I go...

**Update**

This isn't working, despite the recommended changes to the App settings. I am now looking into this issue with other async calls:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/353458578076232?browse=search_506192588df614017400920

And it looks like others are having the same problem:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/498181603534748?browse=search_506192588df614017400920

Answer (score -1):

The wrong in the link of the ifream you have to add http://

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://my.site.com/folder/&send=false&layout=button_count&width=120&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=20" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:20px;">
```

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue. The protocol is left out intentionally because it's taken from the host page then. A page running on https will include https://www.facebook.com/..., a page on plain http will use http://www.facebook.com/...