# Like Box Displays Empty iframe for Some Pages, But Not Others

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, box

So the company I work for has a site that has pages for partners, and on those pages, we're displaying the Like Box for the partner's Facebook page. We're using the iframe method of embedding the Like Box, but I get the same results when using the HTML5 method.

Some of the Like Boxes display the iframe, the width and height of the frame take up space on the page, but no content. Inside the empty frame, the HTML tag looks like this:

```
<html class="no_js" id="facebook" lang="en">
```

In the ones that do display the Facebook content, it looks like this:

```
<html lang="en" class="" id="facebook">
```

It appears to not display the content in all versions of IE and Chrome, but will display for me in Firefox. Others are reporting that it doesn't display the Facebook content in any browser.

I'm at a loss to figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seriously? Nothing? Nothing at all?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'll make sure never to ask a question here again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that in the iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F ...
```

you are using proper address: "www.facebook" - not for example "web.facebook".

Look also at stackoverflow: ["Facebook like button disappears"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874487/facebook-like-button-disappears/12553403)